# How to iterate over record fields?

Tags: haskell, records

I have following datatype defined as record

```
data Config = Config
  { field1 :: String
  , field2 :: String
  , field3 :: String
  }
```

I want to iterate over each field of `Config`, apply some function `String -> String`, for example `tail` and get in return new `Config`.

What is idiomatic way to do this? Preferably, without heavy 3rd party libraries.

Comment: The `head` function returns a `Char`. Am I correct to understand that you want the type of your fields to change depending on what the supplied function returns?

Comment: uniplate is a lightweight generics library that can probably do that easily.

Comment: @MichaelSteele my fault, something like `tail` which will return same type `String`. I've updated questions

Comment: In the case of `tail`, @leftroundabout's answer is the one to use. Note that even though you are looking for a function Config -> Config, you'll want to add a type variable to the definition of Config (as in @leftroundabout's answer) so that `fmap` can do the work for you.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking by analogy with a dynamically typed language where this would be a natural thing to do. In Haskell its not impossible, but in general each field of a data structure would represent a different type of thing, and hence be processed with a different function. The look of your structure seems to suggest a dictionary or array, in which case Data.Map or Array might be more suitable.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Yes. I'm sure. My config fields have 3 different kind of data inside `yaml` field - "data", "data:data" and "data:data:data". Since, I don't want to write parser, I'm using `decodeFile` one-liner. It's easier for me to read through config to datatype and then provide case logic for fields afterwards

Answer (score 16):

Well, the best way to do it would probably be

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

type Config = Config' String
data Config' a = Config
  { field1 :: a
  , field2 :: a
  , field3 :: a
  } deriving (Functor)

configHeads :: Config -> Config' Char
configHeads = fmap head
```

Comment: monotraversable would be an alternative.

Comment: For strings, this seems like the obvious way to go. It's unfortunate that this approach prevents nice optimizations in some other situations.